# Web Api 2 OWIN Selfhost handle multiple concurrent requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, owin-middleware

I have a selfhosted web api using OWIN, and I seems to struggle on concurrent connections. When I run a stress test with 50 concurrent get events, the response time is increasing A LOT, even tho the operation is quite simple, return 200 OK with the id typed in the uri.

How do I my web api OWIN and api controllers to run simultanious per requests??

Here's a sample of my project:

Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            appBuilder.UseWelcomePage("/welcome.html");
            appBuilder.UseErrorPage(new ErrorPageOptions
            {
                ShowExceptionDetails =
    #if DEBUG
                true
    #else
                false
    #endif
            });

            Debug.WriteLine($"Setting Web Api Configuration up...");
            var apiConfig = ConfigureWebApi();
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(new HttpServer(apiConfig));
            appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            Debug.WriteLine($"Completed Web Api configuration.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to complete Web Api setup.", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        return Task<IHttpActionResult>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            try
            {
                return Ok(id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message, nameof(Get));
                return InternalServerError();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My console startup of web api:

```
public static void Open()
{
    _webApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>(HostAddress);
    Console.WriteLine($"Host open -> {HostAddress}");
}
```

Comment: How are you doing your stress test?  Can you post that code?

Comment: Also, rather than doing Factory.StartNew, you can return Task.FromResult(Ok(Id)) which is less likely to block.  Not sure if that would cause your problems though.

Comment: Using Paessler's Webserver Stress tool to perform the stress test. Thinking about creating a simple client instead and see how it goes. Thanks for the tip with Task.FromResult.

Comment: I think you would be better off creating your own test client.  I don't think Paessler's tool will properly test WebApi.  It appears to be more for traditional HTML web pages.

Comment: You are using a thread just to return a 200. That is a performance penalty. Why are you doing that? You do not *need* to create Task based methods in your controller. You are not doing anything that benefits from multithreading this way.

Comment: @PeterBons The example is simplified to keep other logics out of scope. The production one is issuing a EF repository hence the Task operations to simulate the behavior. I'm still quiet new in Web Api, but after what I get from https://www.asp.net/web-api making your ApiController method async Task's, should make the processing asynchronious, right?

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox I have created a little test tool, that basicly start a HttpClient instance in a task. I then realized that the tracing on WebApi I ran in debug, caused the performance hit, probably because the tracer isn't running async. And now I'm even able to hit my rate limiting rules, so thats great. It still leaves me with my original question, is there any better way of doing concurrent operations in the web api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your api controller methods will run simultaneously, obviously limited by the capabilities of the server hosting the api.  That is a function of the web server, whether it is IIS or self hosted.  There are, however, things that you can do to help that along.

If you keep everything asynchronous all the way through, you will see the best performance.  For example, if you controller method looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var testObject = await _repository.GetAsync(id);

    return Ok(testObject);
}
```

and you have a repository method that looks like this:

```
public async Task<TestObject> GetAsync(int id)
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
    {
        // using Dapper
        return await connection.QuerySingleAsync<TestObject>("sp_GetTestObject", new {Id = id}, commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

Doing this allows the computer to use worker threads for the database I/O, freeing processing power for handling other tasks, such as accepting other requests to the API endpoint.  Someone like @StephenCleary can probably expound on what I say and/or correct it.  @StephenCleary's [blog](http://stephencleary.com/) and book are definitely worth a read to understand asynchronous programming.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's excatly what I was looking for. Seems to run as smooth as possible now.